# javascript current value to session variable

Tags: javascript

Hi I am trying to insert a button that carried out an event.

The serverside event code does work manually.

But what is not working in my button is that I am using javascript to get the current value of my field to save it as a session variable which is then put into the server side code.

I am using this code:

```
var ctrl1 = Runner.getControl(pageid, 'PosPostCode');
var value1 = ctrl1.getValue();
params["value1"] = value1;
```

To try and get the `PostCode` field from my php page, and then recalling it later by using `$postcode = $values["PostCode"]`;

The problem is this only works when I edit a record, it doesn't work when I add a new value.

By this I mean that when I have my add new record page open, the javascript is unable to get anything , how do I change this so that I get the live data from the field `PostCode`.

Comment: Why did you put java as a tag when none of the code in your question is in Java?

Comment: Because its sample code I got that I thought was java.  I just need anyone to tell me a java code that will fetch the value of 'postcode' in the current form.

Comment: We need more relevant code to address your problem better.